# Linq to Sql DataContext Thread safety

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, thread-safety, deadlock

Code:

```
using (var db = new TestDataContext(connectionString))
{
    var result = db.usp_Update_TestTable(id, state);
}
```

The update stored procedure `usp_Update_TestTable` is very simple, it just updates the `TestTable`.

Question:

I want to understand if multiple threads are running, and thread A starts updating the table and at the same time thread B calls same method. what will happen.

1. Thread B will wait for Thread A to finish its operation?
2. Thread B will try to update and fail because thread A is still doing its job. hence timeout?
3. Thread B and Thread A will do a deadlock?

If option 3 is the answer then, is there any way to make this operation thread safe?

Thanks.

Comment: did u used `async/await` before?

Comment: yes, in fact this method is called by async methods, hence the multiple threads.

Comment: then you don't worry about all of above 3 points you mentioned the `async/await` takes care about it

Comment: There is no indication that you will have a thread-safety issue, since each thread will have their own `TestDataContext`. You may have issues with **database locking** (as opposed to C# deadlock) - it is impossible to give guidance on that without a [mcve] including the source code of  `usp_Update_TestTable`.

Comment: mjwills, you have hit the nail in the head, yes I have db lock issues. usp_Update_TestTable is simply Update TestTable set state = @state where id=@id.

Comment: Please update your question with that detail. Also, please re-read [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

Hi here is the link https://dzone.com/articles/parallel-sql-c here it explains the use of task library to achive the thread safety through parallel programming, and ofcourse async/waits too works for this scenario.